# How do I get Python Timedelta to rollover to the next day when calculating time elapsed?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a function that takes in the hour and minute of two programs and returns the elapsed time. It works well when the end_time isn't the next day. If it's the next day, I get a negative number. What's the best way to resolve this?

```
def elapsed_time_seconds(hour_start,hour_end,minute_start,minute_end):
    hour_start = int(hour_start)
    minute_start = int(minute_start)
    hour_end = int(hour_end)
    minute_end = int(minute_end)
    
    t1 = timedelta(hours=hour_start,minutes=minute_start)
    t2 = timedelta(hours=hour_end,minutes=minute_end)
    
    return (t2-t1).total_seconds()
```

If a program starts at 11:30 PM, and ends at 3:00 AM, we expect it to return 12600 seconds. However this is what I get currently:

```
elapsed_time_seconds('23','03','00','00')

-72000.0
```

What is the best way to resolve this edge case? The function works fine when the start time and end time are on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if `t1 > t2` and if so add 24 hours to `t2`:

```py
from datetime import timedelta


def elapsed_time_seconds(hour_start, hour_end, minute_start, minute_end):
    hour_start = int(hour_start)
    minute_start = int(minute_start)
    hour_end = int(hour_end)
    minute_end = int(minute_end)

    t1 = timedelta(hours=hour_start, minutes=minute_start)
    t2 = timedelta(hours=hour_end, minutes=minute_end)

    if t1 > t2:
        t2 += timedelta(hours=24)

    return (t2 - t1).total_seconds()


print(elapsed_time_seconds("23", "03", "30", "00"))
```

Output:

```
12600.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this edge case **by checking if the end time is smaller than the start time**, which indicates the end time is on the next day. If that's the case, you can add 24 hours (or 86400 seconds) to the elapsed time to account for the day change:

```py
from datetime import timedelta


def elapsed_time_seconds(hour_start: str, hour_end: str, minute_start: str, minute_end: str) -> int:
    hour_start = int(hour_start)
    minute_start = int(minute_start)
    hour_end = int(hour_end)
    minute_end = int(minute_end)

    t1 = timedelta(hours=hour_start, minutes=minute_start)
    t2 = timedelta(hours=hour_end, minutes=minute_end)

    elapsed = (t2 - t1).total_seconds()

    # Check if the end time is on the next day
    if elapsed < 0:
        elapsed += timedelta(days=1).total_seconds()

    return elapsed
```